# "Inner" routing in AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm developing new app using AngularJS and ASP.NET. This is first time when I'm using Angular and I have a little problem with this.
I used one project as a kind of template. This is it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791740/Using-AngularJs-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-and-EntityFram
I created additional view in which I tree as a submenu, I used abn-tree for this. It looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="dictionaryController as dicitonaryCtrl">
        <div class="panel-heading">Dictionary</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <abn-tree tree-data="dicitonaryCtrl.dicitonaryData" expand-level="1" ></abn-tree>
        </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do now is do some kind of routing. I use data-ng-view for main routing, but here I want to just load some data from controller and change content of one div after clicking on item on tree. I just want to make it work like my main menu, but change different div. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used anguar-router module which is having only one view (ng-view) and you can not implement nested/sub views.

please try [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) modue which will solve your problem and you can implement nested/sub views (ui-view)

Comment: Thanks. I will check it now. But cannot I achive my goal by using data-ng-include?

Comment: No, ng-include is a directive to separate a layout/containers (like header, footer, sidebar..etc.)..you can not load a specific page/content in a particuar container by clicking link/element is not possible.